# Extract variable from string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 'Description' column in my database.
This column contains various product description.
In the description for each product the price is mentioned.

The format is alwasys like 'Apples for 10 EUR/month with bag included', 'Tomatos for 9 EUR/month with bag included' and so on.

I want to extract the extract only the price for these products, i.e. '10', '9', etc.

```
select SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION, 0, INSTR(DESCRIPTION, 'EUR/month') - 1)
  from PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
 where PRODUCT IN ('Apples', 'Tomatos');
```

I used the above script, but the results I get are: 'Apples for 10', 'Tomatos for 9', etc.

Do you know what condition should i use in order to get only the cost?

Answer (score 0):

If that is always the structure, then just take out the number:

```
select regexp_substr(description, '[0-9.]+')
from product_description
```

Comment: Only the information regarding the cost is always the same, meaning 10 EUR/month. Unfortunately, the script you've shared doesn't work.

Comment: @Florin.Tns: Gordon's query matches the format you have given perfectly. So in what way doesn't it work? What other formats are there that keep this solution from working?

Comment: Ah, right, it should be `'[0-9]+'` instead of `'[0-9.]*'`. (And an additional `.` and/or `,` if the values can have decimals and/or thousand separators.)

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the rest with regexp_replace and make use of the grouping.

```
select regexp_replace(DESCRIPTION, '.*\s+(\d+)\s*EUR.*','\1') 
-- You are using the grouping of regexp, and reuse the number that has been found
from PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
```